# Sequelize Find belongsToMany Association

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have an association m:n between two tables with sequelize like this:

**Course**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
     .....
    },
    {
      associate: function(models){
        Course.hasMany(models.Schedule);
        Course.belongsTo(models.Period);
        Course.belongsTo(models.Room);
        Course.belongsTo(models.Subject);
        Course.belongsTo(models.School);
        Course.belongsTo(models.Person, { as: 'Teacher' });
      }
    }
  );
 return Course;
};
```

**Person**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
    ....
    },
    {
      associate: function(models){
        Person.belongsTo(models.Role, { as: 'Role' });
        Person.belongsTo(models.School, { as: 'School' });
        Person.belongsTo(models.Person, { as: 'Tutor' });
      }
    }
  );

  return Person;
};
```

And the association table **Enrollment**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Enrollment = sequelize.define('Enrollment', {
      ....
    },
    {
      associate: function(models){
        Enrollment.belongsTo(models.Product, {as: 'Product'});
        Enrollment.belongsTo(models.School, { as: 'School' });

        models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Course, {through: {model: Enrollment},foreignKey: 'StudentEnrollId'});
        models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, {through: {model: Enrollment},foreignKey: 'CourseEnrollId'});

      }
    }

  );
  return Enrollment;
};
```

I tried following this "[example](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations)" but doesn't explain much rather than a simple query where include the parameter through.

What I trying to archive is to get All the courses given a Student id (Person Model). As you can see the course model only saves the id of differents tables that together form a course. The Person Model also is associate to differents models so I give a custom id name with `foreignKey: 'StudentEnrollId'` but when I try to specify the id name in the include `model : db.Person, as: 'StundetEnroll'` the query show the following error: `Person (StudentEnroll) is not associated to Course`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the alias `as` also in the `belongsToMany` association

```
models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Course, { as: 'CourseEnrolls', through: { model: Enrollment }, foreignKey: 'StudentEnrollId'});
models.Course.belongsToMany(models.Person, { as: 'StudentEnrolls', through: { model: Enrollment }, foreignKey: 'CourseEnrollId'});
```

Now you will be able to query `Course` with all it's students and vice-versa

```
models.Course.findByPrimary(1, {
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Person,
            as: 'StudentEnrolls'
        }
    ]
}).then(course => {
    // course.StudentEnrolls => array of Person instances (students of given course)
});
```

You can also use `get/set Associations` methods in order to retrieve or set associated objects

```
// assuming that course is an instance of Course model
course.getStudentEnrolls().then(students => {
    // here you get all students of given course
});
```

Comment: Thanks, That helped me a lot. Now I only have to play with the includes to get the other datas.